# Trying to delete proposition from a paragrapgh

Tags: javascript, arrays

Am trying to delete all the proposition from a paragraph but if two proposition is repeating only first one is deleted from paragraph, not the second one??

```
function checkForSameWords() {
  var valueOfArray1 = textArea1.value.trim().split(" ");
  var commons = ["a", "the", "of", "are", "is", "am", "with", "on", "at", "from", "to", "on", "must"];
  removingProposition(valueOfArray1, commons);
}

function removingProposition(paragraph, proposition) {
  for (var i = 0; i < paragraph.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < preposition.length; j++) {
      if (paragraph[i] === proposition[j]) {
        var h = paragraph.splice(paragraph.indexOf(paragraph[i]), 1);

      }
    }
  }
  console.log(paragraph);
}
```

Comment: Hi Akash. Welcome to StackOverflow. In the future, please properly format your code. It will make users more likely to read and answer your question. See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your inner for loop, you are using "pr**e**position" instead of "pr**o**position". Other than that, the code seems to work fine.

I have used a random sentence to test the function as I don't know what the value of `textarea1` is.

Additionally, "pr**e**position" is the word you are looking for and I have used it in the code below.

```js
var exampleParagraph = "Once upon a time there was a princess who lived in a castle."

checkForSameWords(exampleParagraph);

function checkForSameWords() {
  var valueOfArray1 = exampleParagraph.trim().split(" ");
  var commons = ["a", "the", "of", "are", "is", "am", "with", "on", "at", "from", "to", "on", "must"];
  removingPreposition(valueOfArray1, commons);
}

function removingPreposition(paragraph, preposition) {
  for (var i = 0; i < paragraph.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < preposition.length; j++) {
      if (paragraph[i] === preposition[j]) {
        var h = paragraph.splice(paragraph.indexOf(paragraph[i]), 1);

      }
    }
  }
  console.log(paragraph);
}
```